# How to return duplicate elements from list c#

Tags: list, return, duplicates

How can i  return and displays two objects with the same value in "storlek" ?

var item = newklädDataList **."maybe something here?"** (e => e.storlek == searchstring);

The app i'm making is a "digital wardrobe" and users can add for exampel a shirt with the elements adidas, shirt, black, small. And i want the app to show all shirts with the value "small" if they search for "small". –

```
string searchstring = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();


        var item = newklädDataList.FirstOrDefault(e => e.storlek == searchstring);

        if (item != null)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            menuTEXT.WriteFullLine("- Din Digitalgarderobs innehåll -");
            Console.WriteLine("~========================================================================~");
            Console.WriteLine("                                                                        ");
            Console.WriteLine("Märke: {0}\tTyp: {1}\tFärg: {2}\tStorlek: {3}                          ", item.märke, item.typ, item.färg, item.storlek);
            Console.WriteLine("                                                                        ");
            Console.WriteLine("~========================================================================~");
            Felhantering.sökaIgen();
        }
        else if (item == null)
        {
            nullResult(searchstring);
        }
```

---

```
public class klädDATALIST //Kläddata sparas här
{

    private static List<klädDATALIST> newklädDataList = new List<klädDATALIST>(); // Lista med klädegenskaper

    public static List<klädDATALIST> GetList() // Metod för att hämta lista
    {
        return newklädDataList;
    }

    public string märke;
    public string typ;
    public string färg; 
    public string storlek;        

    public klädDATALIST(string _märke, string _typ, string _färg, string _storlek) //Överlagrad konstruktor
    {
        this.märke = _märke;
        this.typ = _typ;
        this.färg = _färg;
        this.storlek = _storlek;            
    }
}
```

Comment: so you have a list with, for example different shirts, and when the user searchs for one of those values (adidas, black or small) you want to return als of the shirts which correlate?

Comment: yes! Now it only returns the first in the list :/

Comment: when you replace the FirstOrDefault you get a list back.
newklädDataList.Where(e => e.storlek == searchstring).toList();

Comment: oh i meant it only returns the first matching list, i want it to return all lists with the value

Comment: why do you have more lists? i don't exactly understand what you are doing, it is all a bit abstract to me..

Comment: newklädDataList.Add(new klädDATALIST(_märke, _typ, _färg, _storlek)); saves every new piece of cloth as a new array :)

Comment: but then it should work to replace the FirstOrDefault with Where. Because then you get every list where storlek == searchstring.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable <- then i get this error :/

Comment: i had this error before and there the problem was that i forgot to add "()" behind of the method. do you missed somewhere to add this?

Comment: var item = newklädDataList.Where(e => e.märke == searchstring).ToList<klädDATALIST>(); yes i did but now i got a new error : Error 3 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication8.klädDATALIST>' does not contain a definition for 'färg' and no extension method 'färg' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication8.klädDATALIST>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
(thank you for all your help so far!)

Comment: i am a bit unsure about the ToList<klädDATALIST>(). you only get a list back which includes the filtered klädDATALISTs. so i think you can leave the generics away. and to display the results you have to iterate through the list before you can get the färg of each item. maybe that is your problem? but im wondering why you have a list for every piece of cloth, woudn't it be beter to have a class for this?

Comment: I'm very new at programming hehe, i actually have  a class. I'll write the class in the original post so you can look at it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This was my original code:**

```
 if (newklädDataList[i].färg.Contains(item.färg))
                {                        
                    Console.WriteLine("Märke: {0}\tTyp: {1}\tFärg: {2}\tStorlek: {3}                         ", item.märke, item.typ, item.färg, item.storlek);
                }
```

**And this is my code that works as i wanted it:**

```
 if (newklädDataList[i].färg.Contains(item.färg))
                {
                    klädDATALIST plagg = newklädDataList[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Märke: {0}\tTyp: {1}\tFärg: {2}\tStorlek: {3}                         ", plagg.märke, plagg.typ, plagg.färg, plagg.storlek);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Ok, I think I understand now how it should look like, correct me when im wrong.
I wrote a litle test programm where i wrote all the words in english.

so i have the class Stuff:

```
    public class Stuff{

            public string brand;
            public string type;
            public string color;
            public string size;

            public Stuff(string argBrand, string argType, string argColor, string argSize){
                brand = argBrand;
                type = argType;
                color = argColor;
                size = argSize;
            }
    }
```

this is the same as yours, but I didn't put the list in there.
Then i have the main class:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Stuff> AllStuff = new List<Stuff>();

        Stuff stuff = new Stuff("adidas", "test", "test", "test");
        Stuff stuff2 = new Stuff("adidas", "test2", "test", "test");
        Stuff stuff3 = new Stuff("nike", "test3", "test", "test");
        Stuff stuff4 = new Stuff("nike", "test4", "test", "test");
        Stuff stuff5 = new Stuff("puma", "test5", "test", "test");
        AllStuff.Add(stuff);
        AllStuff.Add(stuff2);
        AllStuff.Add(stuff3);
        AllStuff.Add(stuff4);
        AllStuff.Add(stuff5);

        string searchstring = "nike";

        var items = AllStuff.Where(s => s.brand.Equals(searchstring)).ToList();

        foreach(var item in items){
            Console.WriteLine("brand: " + item.brand + " " + item.type);
        }
    }
```

There I have a list where I add all the Stuff I want. Then I iterate over the list to filter all objects where the brand is equals the searchstring (for strings you normaly not take the == because there it checks the object reference, and this is not what you want to. with equals it checks the correct thing). There i got a list of Stuff objects back. In the foreach loop I take every item in the list and print it on the console.
And thats the output:

```
brand: nike test3
brand: nike test4
```

I hope this is what you wanted, otherwise let me know.

Comment: The app i'm making is a "digital wardrobe" and users can add for exampel a shirt with the elements adidas, shirt, black, small. And i want the app to show all shirts with the value "small" if they search for "small".

Comment: was this answer what you expected, or do you need some further help?